# How to add blurred render layer on top of the other? Screen and alpha over not doing what I hoped

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Ive got this render layer
[image]

And this

[image]

I want to put the "sun" on top of the white in the first render layer. Looked at a similar case in a book and they used screen, but as you can see it does not work for me (3rd picture).

[image]

I can get the sun in with an alpha over, but then the blur gets cropped to the size of the sun in the second layer like this
[image]
The result from the two blur nodes are actually bigger.

Anyone have a solution to getting that sun in blurred? I feel like an idiot not solving this

Comment: Screen is a garbage operation in a light transport model, and can only work on probability based ideas (0-100%) so it is wise to start by getting it out of the radiometric emission chain.

Comment: Elaborate please, why is it garbage? @troy_s

Comment: The Screen blend mode. You’ll need to remove it. I’m not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with the dual blur nodes, so a bit of clarification there will help. Start by removing that broken Screen merge however. Not sure what the alpha over in the upper image is achieving either.

Comment: Screen is `A + B - (A * B)` which _is a broken idea_ with respect to radiometric emissions. It doesn’t work on anything beyond percentages. As you can see, if our emission for a is 21.2 and our B is 23.4, the subtraction would result in a negative value. Screen is an anachronistic hand me down from Adobe’s PDF specification, and is largely garbage in the context of proper radiometric emissions.

Comment: Got it from the good old guru. Page 15 https://www.loop.la/descargas/librosanim/blender/The%20Wow%20Factor%20Book.pdf . The alpha over is just used to put the render layer on top of the environment layer, not very necessary, but it doesn't hurt. But do you have a solution for putting the sun blurred on top of a white background? Non of the blend modes for the color node seems to do it. @troy_s

Comment: It should composite just fine via a simple alpha over. You’d need to check the plates however. Technically, if it is a render, the blur is simply directly applied to the associated alpha RGBA image, then composited. The deep “white” background would need to be something that corresponds with your display rendering transform, for example under Filmic, R=G=B emissions of 2^6.5 * 0.18. Should be the two images, one blur, two alpha overs.